# How to calculate distance between multiple lon lat vectors using R

Tags: r, ggmap

My data set is as below-

```
a
Location   loc.Lon   loc.Lat  Pincode      pin.lon     pin.lat
SPM        79.94533 12.97025 "602105"   79.95285     12.96752
SPM        79.94533 12.97025 "602106"   79.88568     12.91943
```

I want to calculate the distance between (loc.Lon, loc.Lat) and (pin.lon, pin.lat) for both the pincodes using the package ggmap.

when I run the below code, I get the desired result -

```
mapdist(c(a$loc.Lon[2], a$loc.Lat[2]), c(a$pin.lon[2],a$pin.lat[2]), mode = "driving")
```

but when I run the below query for the entire data set a, I get an error -

```
a$dist = mapdist(c(a$loc.Lon, a$loc.Lat), c(a$pin.lon,a$pin.lat), mode = "driving")
```

error I get is -

```
Error: is.character(from) is not TRUE
```

Please help me getting this sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapdist` accepts vectors for the `from` and `to` arguments, so you can convert them and apply this function to each line of you data set.

Supposing you want the km distance:

```
get_km_from_mapdist <- function(i) {
  mapdist(as.numeric(a[i, c('loc.Lon','loc.Lat')]), 
          as.numeric(a[i, c('pin.lon','pin.lat')]), 
          mode='driving')$km
}

a$dists = sapply(1:nrow(a), get_km_from_mapdist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the coordinates as strings with `as.character()` and `paste0()` them when calling `mapdist` directly onto your data.

```
a$dist_km <- mapdist(from = paste0(as.character(a$loc.Lat),",",as.character(a$loc.Lon)),
                     to = paste0(as.character(a$pin.Lat),", ",as.character(a$pin.Lon)))[,c('km')]
```